# Looking for a script to download content from RSS feed

Tags: xml, rss, download

Is anyone aware of an app or script example designed to download content from an RSS feed?

Comment: Hi, which platform, which language please

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with [XML::Feed](http://search.cpan.org/~simonw/XML-Feed-0.43/lib/XML/Feed.pm)